# la web se rompe en chrome en algunos moviles por la animacion @keyframes

Tags: css, animación, keyframes

La web en mi dispositivo en chrome se rompe pero con el mismo en otros dispositivos anda excelente ...

Al igual que si lo veo en chrome en mi dispositivo lo veo mal, pero en mozilla bien ...

Además al probarlo en browserstack me pasa lo mismo algunos se rompe otros no con el mismo navegador diferentes dispositivos...

adjunto video para que sea mas claro.

Alguno sabe porque sucede esto?? intenté con las reglas de webkit pero no funciono...

https://www.loom.com/share/c0a67708ca32433da68406e7abf9823f

```
.backgroundimg {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

}

#back1 {
    background: url("../img/fondo.webp") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;


}

#back2 {
    background: url("../img/WhatsApp Image 2021-09-21 at 03.45.46.webp") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;

}

#back3 {
    background: url("../img/fondo.webp") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}

#back4 {
    background: url("../img/WhatsApp Image 2021-09-21 at 03.45.46.webp") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;

}

#back5 {
    background: url("../img/fondo.webp") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}

@keyframes backgroundchangeFadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  92% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}
#backgroundchange div:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 20s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 20s;
}
#backgroundchange div:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay:15s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:15s;
}
#backgroundchange div:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 10s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}
#backgroundchange div:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}

#backgroundchange div:nth-of-type(5) {
  animation-delay: 0;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
}

#backgroundchange div {
animation-name: backgroundchangeFadeInOut;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-duration: 20s;

-webkit-animation-name: backgroundchangeFadeInOut;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-duration: 20s;

}
```

Comment: Añade el código con el que estás trabajando